# yii camel case class filenames in linux

Tags: yii

I have created my first Yii application. I used Gii Model generator for creating models.For example, I created my Model Class name as **ProductManager** and in the CURD generator the Controller ID as **productManager**. Everything was working fine in my XAMPP server, but when I uploaded it to my online linux hosting.
 I got the php include file error. It is looking for models/Productmanager.php, but when I changed the file name from ProductManager.php to Productmanager.php there is error in another model file.
Also I have to use the Camel case URL name for Controllers in the online server. Can anyone please explain how to configure the Gii , so that it will work without any problems in linux hosting servers.

Comment: nobody in the yii framework who can help me?

Comment: Which line in which file do you get the error on? What is the call stack at that time? What does the offending line read?

Comment: include(Modelmaster.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

/www/site/framework/YiiBase.php(418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gii uses the name of your table to create the model name. Did you name your table productmanager or product_manager? The latter will allow Gii to automatically create a model with the name ProductManager (CamelCase), else it will be Productmanager.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The model name is created as ProductManager, UserMaster etc, but the error occurs when a relational model is called, the model file name is not called in the CamelCase format.
I am getting the following error.

include(Modelmaster.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory /www/site/framework/YiiBase.php

Comment: This is because Gii uses table names when generating relational model names. If the table name is modelmaster instead of model_master, Gii will create a relation with the relational model named Modelmaster.

Comment: And in that case a model named Modelmaster does not exist because it was named ModelMaster by the user in most cases.